# Trouble running Tensorboard from IPython Console

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have saved the Tensorboard log files in the following directory

> /tmp/mnist_tutorial/

and Now When I am trying to run the tensorboard from `IPython Console` using command

> tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist_tutorial/

I am getting the following error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anybody tell me how can I overcome this issue

Comment: tensorboard is a separate program, not python function. You should execute it from shell. Or if you insist, you can execute shell commands from ipython py prepending it with '!' , like  

!tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist_tutorial/

Comment: @DmitryVyal On running the above command and moving on to "http://localhost:6006/" on browser I am getting the following error

`No dashboards are active for the current data set.`
`Probable causes:`
`You haven’t written any data to your event files.`
`TensorBoard can’t find your event files.`

Comment: Then likely tensorboard is pointing to the wrong directory or there are no event files. Are there files in the mnist tutorial directory?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos log files are located in the following directory "D:\tmp\mnist_tutorial"

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the syntax error and the contents of the mnist_tutorial directory?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I retrain the code by changing `/tmp/mnist_tutorial/` to `tmp/mnist_tutorial/` and it worked